# Using Parameter in Ajax jQuery / Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am trying to use jQuery. To update a specific TD with innerHTML I am trying to figure out, how I can catch the value of the parameter.

In this example i need to catch the user-id "1234" so i can update the TD with the ID "status1234".

I am not very familar with javascript, I hope someone can give me a hint.

```js
$(function() {
  $('.ajax-link').click(function() {
    $.get($(this).attr('href'), function(msg) {
      alert("Data Saved: " + msg);
      $("#status" & user).html("some content");
    });
    return false;
  });
});
```

```html
// TD with Link:

<td id="status1234">
  <a href="/ajax_test.cfm?user=1234" class="ajax-link">Do the Ajax</a>
</td>
```

Thanx!

Comment: What is `$("#status" & user)` supposed to mean? `&` is bit-wise AND, why would you use it with strings? To concatenate strings you use `+`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may do like this

```js
       $(function() {
  $('.ajax-link').click(function() {
  var user=$(this).data('user');
    $.get("/"+$(this).data('url')+"/user="+user, function(msg) {
      alert("Data Saved: " + msg);
      $("#status" + user).html("some content");
    });
  
  });
   });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<td id="status1234">
      <a data-url="ajax_test.cfm" data-user="1234" class="ajax-link">Do the Ajax</a>
    </td>
```

Answer (score 0):

Do this..

```
$(function() {
   $('.ajax-link').click( function() {
     var userTd = $(this).parent().attr('id');
     $.get( $(this).attr('href'), function(msg) {
          alert( "Data Saved: " + msg );
          $("#"+userTd ).html("some content");
     });
     return false;
  });
});
```